# Unable to parameterize through database table in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a simple script which should read values from a DB table and pass the values to an HTTP request. So My JDBC request is able to fetch the table values. I have added a counter to parametrize the values. I have added the variable entityName=${_*V(Dataset_Name*${counter})} in my actual http request. But somehow it is taking the variable names from the jdbc request and incrementing the same instead of taking the values from DB table. So in the http request i am getting the variablename_1 variable name_2 as values instead of the DB table values. What am i doing wrong here??
[image: JDBC Request]
enter image description here
[![JDBC Request[image: HTTP Request]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your query returns what it is supposed to return using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination.
2. The correct syntax of the [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) given your approach would be

   ```
   ${__V(Dataset_Name_${counter},)}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Broader question, is the target of your query the same database as that which is used for your application under test?   If so, then you are adding significant load as each of the users connects to and pulls data from the database directly.

Have you considered preloading a queue with the results of a query to address this need?